# Why is my NSMutableArray "half dead" in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

In rootViewController.h i have a property NSMutableArray mainList:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {    
    NSMutableArray *mainList;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mainList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailsViewController *detailsController;
```

In the m file, when loading, the following works just fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.mainList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Country1", @"Contry2", nil];
}
```

Populating the array by a class also works fine (on first load):

```
innehall *myInnehall= [[innehall alloc] init];
[myInnehall fillMain];
self.mainList = myInnehall.theMainList;
[myInnehall release];
```

(the debugger shows data to be correct in the array)

When scrolling, the app crasches at setting the label of the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [self.mainList objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
return cell;
}
```

In the debugger, the Array is only populated 1-9 instead of up to 19. 10-19 containing strange objects. What can be eating my Array??

Comment: None of the code you posted looks like a source of that problem.  When you use the first method of populating the array does anything strange happen.  You only mentioned a problem when you populate by a class.  The problem might come from the code where you allocate, populate and release myInnehall.theMainList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
self.mainList = myInnehall.theMainList;
```

to

```
self.mainList = [myInnehall.theMainList copy];
```

Can you also put `NSLog([self.mainList description])` in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and post the result?

---

**PS:** You have NSMutableArray in property declaration and you initialize it as NSArray?

Comment: Thank you Kashiv, the problem is solved by copying rather then pointing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your NSMutableArray property must be initialized properly, like:

`self.mainList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

(Not as a `NSArray`)

Then, you are making your property `mainList` point to `myInnehall.theMainList` and you are releasing it afterwards, that is what is causing the crash.

Try just add the `myInnehall` items to your `mainList`

`[self.mainList addObjectsFromArray:myInnehall.theMainList];`

Comment: PS: please dont copy your object... Just add the existent items to your array, off course unless you are pretty clear about how NSArray implements the NSCopying protocol.